# ivar of Swift Actor in objc code: atomic or nonatomic?

Tags: swift, objective-c, actor, bridge

If I have a swift Actor...

```
@objc public actor SomeActor: NSObject, SomeProtocol { ... }
```

...and I want to use it as an ivar in objc code, does it need to be listed as atomic to retain it's thread safety, or is it more performant to call it nonatomic?

Also, do I need to be referencing it with a getter to preserve its thread safety, or can I call it directly?

```
#import <ThisProject/ThisProject-Swift.h>

@interface SomeClass () <SomeId>
@property (strong, atomic, readwrite) SomeActor *someActor;
@end

...

    [SomeOtherClass someMethod:someActor];
```

vs

```
@interface SomeClass () <SomeId>
@property (strong, nonatomic, readwrite) SomeActor *someActor;
@end
    
...

    [SomeOtherClass someMethod:_someActor];
```

Comment: IMO (from experience) once you have to deal with objc, you can forget all the promises the swift concurrency gives you (including actor isolation) - it's just a class for objc. So how you handle that class very much depends on context.

Comment: Hmm. This has not been my experience. The actor isolation has always worked fine for me when called from Objective-C. If you have a chance, I’d love to see MRE where actor-isolation is not honored. IMHO, the only major annoyance that you cannot expose non-`async` isolated methods via `@objc` (as discussed in the [SE-0297](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0297-concurrency-objc.md#actor-classes)).

Comment: Just always use `nonatomic` and properties. Ivars directly should be used only in initializers. For synchronisation use other tools. It's Apple's style: swift is example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While Alexander answered your question (and you should feel free to accept [his answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77810175/1271826); +1), I offer a few clarifying observations:

1. **What is the purpose of `atomic`?**

   The `atomic` qualifier on the property just dictates how Objective-C synthesized accessors handle the *pointer* to the actor and has nothing to with the actor’s internal behaviors. As the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH5-SW37) says, `atomic` “means that the synthesized accessors ensure that a value [the pointer in this case] is always fully retrieved by the getter method or fully set via the setter method, even if the accessors are called simultaneously from different threads.”

   The `atomic` keyword simply ensures that the synthesized accessor methods atomically fetch and store the pointer address, itself. It has no bearing on the internal thread-safety (or lack thereof) of the object to which it points.
2. **Should one use `atomic` or `nonatomic`?**

   In practice, `atomic` often introduces (admittedly negligible) overhead with limited benefit. Like Alexander, I almost always use `nonatomic`. If the Objective-C code has thread-safety issues, one often needs a higher-level of synchronization, rendering the `atomic` nature to the pointer largely moot. It depends the Objective-C code (which is not really relevant to the immediate question).

   But, as Alexander pointed out, whether you mark the property as `atomic` or `nonatomic` is irrelevant to the fact that you are pointing to an `actor` or some other `class`.
3. **Should you use the property getter, `self.someActor`, or access the backing ivar, `_someActor`?**

   You did not explicitly ask this question, but one of your examples, you refer to `someActor` (which I presume means you intended to use the getter, though given the absence of either `self.` or the leading underscore, it is not entirely clear) and in the other, `_someActor` (the property’s backing ivar).

   As [Programming with Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH5-SW5) says, “… it’s best practice for an object to access its own properties using accessor methods or dot syntax.” The two common exceptions to this rule are (a) in `init`; and (b) in manually implemented getters/setters, if any.

   So, in short, I would generally use `self.someActor` and not `_someActor`.

   Please note, I belabor this accessor vs. ivar distinction because the `atomic`/`nonatomic` only dictates the nature of the synthesized accessor methods. It has no effect on direct interaction via the ivar. Thus, an `atomic` ivar is a bit of a non-sequitur, as directly interacting with the ivar bypasses the accessors and their synthesized behaviors (including `atomic`), too.

Bottom line, feel free to use `nonatomic`. And if you are trying to ensure that the Objective-C code, itself, is thread-safe, we would need to see any relevant code, but, generally, merely making the property `atomic` would be insufficient. The fact that you are dealing with an `actor` has no meaningful impact on the choice of `atomic` or `nonatomic`.

---

For folks looking for a description of `actor` interoperability with Objective-C, see [SE-0297 – Concurrency Interoperability with Objective-C](https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0297-concurrency-objc.md#actor-classes).

Comment: Both answers were great, but this was especially clarifying. I was actually trying to ask question 3 on here too, but was probably not clear enough. Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

The `atomic` keyword is about the *storage* about the property itself, e.g. in this case, the `SomeActor *` pointer. All it guarantees is that changes to the pointer are done atomically.

It has nothing to do with the semantics of the pointed-to thing, such as your actor.

It's not often that I find that my synchronization issues are about settings specific fields. It's usually about synchronizing entire objects or collections, so I find the whole `atomic` feature pretty dubious. I just always go `nonatomic`.